# Script that prints certain numbers

Tags: python, list

How would I write a python script that prints numbers 30 through 100 by every ten but excludes a certain value like 50?

Comment: `for n in range(30, 101, 10): if n not in [50, 60]: print(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
excluded_numbers = [50]
for num in range(30, 101, 10):
    if num not in excluded_numbers:
        print(num)
```